# Idle in transaction: How to get the query caused

Tags: database, postgresql

My application executes many queries and it is sure that all connections are closed well. PgAdmin shows many queries have gone "Idle in transaction" and finally DB becomes unresponsive.  Is there a way to get the query caused to be 'Idle in transaction' ? Or any other tool which can track it ? Postgres 8.1 is used.
**Edit**: Connection Pool is used. Also, the state ' in transaction' got cleared after couple of minutes. Then, if any connection is opened, how this get cleared ?

Comment: 8.1 is no longer supported or maintained. You should upgrade **now**. And if you do, you can see the most recent query of a session directly in `pg_stat_activity`:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW

Comment: If the connection goes from `idle in transactio` to `idle` this means your application has properly ended the transaction e.g. by issuing a `commit`. Or the connection pool has done that because the you configured some orphaned connection cleanup.

Answer (score 6):

If you check information in [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/monitoring-ps.html) regarding this:

> idle in transaction (waiting for client inside a BEGIN block), or a
>   command type name such as SELECT. Also, waiting is attached if the
>   server process is presently waiting on a lock held by another server
>   process

I would suggest following things:

- enable logging of "long queries" using `log_min_duration_statement`
  and `log_lock_waits` option in *postgresql.conf* in [Error Reporting and Logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html) section
- check [Lock Management](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-locks.html#GUC-DEADLOCK-TIMEOUT) parameters of *postgresql.conf* configuration file,`deadlock_timeout` option in particular
- check [Lock Monitoring](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) article on Postgres Wiki and [`pg_locks`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/view-pg-locks.html) view in Postgres

Comment: when is session in "idle in transaction" then it doesn't wait on lock

Comment: what do you mean by *session* ? application one? author of the question indicated `postgres` itself.  `idle` should be indicated when database is waiting for command @PavelStehule

Comment: the session is +/- equivalent to a connect. Postgres cannot be  `idle in transaction` itself. There have to be opened connections.

Comment: correct - database connection has be opened (it is not app session), but we don't know if app has connection pool or not. secondly, we assume that author is closing all connections he opens manually. @PavelStehule

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I am confused.. bcoz, the state '<the IDLE> in transaction' got cleared after couple of minutes. Then, if any connection is opened, how this get cleared ?

Comment: if `idle in transaction` is cleared it means postgres returned result for particular db connection and after that connection 1) can be just `idle` if your app uses connection pool 2) can be closed - if your app closes connection correctly as Pavel mentioned in his answer @Débora

Comment: @Débora: it simply means the _transaction_ was ended by the application. Either by sending a `commit` or a `rollback`

Answer (score 4):

This is clean signal, so some about closing transaction and closing sessions is wrong in your application. The queries works well. Check your application - unexpected exceptions, fails, ... Some applications are pretty buggy - usually it is **pretty serious** problem. Orphaned transactions block VACUUM and block reusing connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked all of them.. nothing found such... I found resultset and statements opened. I closed them too, but still it shows.

Comment: You have to close opened transactions - or more precious close opened connections. This is 100% application problem - you are using PostgreSQL 8.1 - first, it is unsupported version, second - it has not modern diagnostic - in modern PG you can see a last statement in session - what can be good indicator where is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your support.  I have to have stuck with the older version.  Also, the state '<the IDLE> in transaction' got cleared after couple of minutes. Then, if any connection is opened, how this get cleared ?

Comment: @Débora: you can see some side effects of connection pools. What you use for connection pooling? If you are debugging connections, the best way is temporary remove connection pool from your stack. Your sw have to be correct without any connection pooling. When it is, then you can start connection pooling.